# Forcing immersive full screen from Service on Android

Tags: android, fullscreen, android-4.4-kitkat

I was wondering if it would be possible to force the new immersive full screen feature in Android 4.4 from a background service, which would result in the system being full screen 'at all times'.

The idea was something like 'get the current active View and modify its UI visibility flags accordingly and also listen to system UI visibility changes'.

I'm not experienced in programming for Android so I was wondering if something like this is possible or you cannot modify the system's UI this way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not possible, as "the current active View" is not necessarily in your process.

Comment: Do you know how [this](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=me.dt2dev.fullscreen.free&hl=en) works then?